# Solving a System of ODEs with Variables Dependent on One Another

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have a system of ODEs that I would like to solve for analytically (if possible) for an observable variable, $x(t)$,
$$
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\frac{dk(x)}{dt} &= \sin{(x)} - k(x), \\
\frac{dx}{dt} &= - k(x)\sin(x).
\end{split}
\end{equation}
$$
However, I am not sure how to go about it because of the $k(x)$ dependence in $x$ equation. This is my best attempt to far, but I don't know if I have over-complicated things or not.

$$
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
&\frac{dk(x)}{dt} = \frac{dx}{dt}\frac{dk(x)}{dx} = \sin{(x)} - k(x), \\
&(- k(x)\sin(x))\frac{dk(x)}{dx} = \sin{(x)} - k(x), \\
&\frac{dk(x)}{dx} = -\frac{1}{k(x)} + \frac{1}{\sin{(x)}}
\end{split}
\end{equation}
$$
At this point I am a bit stuck. I don't even really know if trying to solve the $k(x)$ in terms of $x$, as I have tried to do above, is the right way to start out. Any advice on how to approach this type of problem?

Comment: My opinion is that you've done basically all you can. Would love to be proven wrong though

Answer (score 1):

$$
k(x)=-\frac{dx}{dt}\csc(x)\\
\frac{d(k(x))}{dt}=\csc(x)\cot(x)\left(\frac{dx}{dt}\right)^2+\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}\csc(x)
$$

So
$$
\csc(x)\cot(x)\left(\frac{dx}{dt}\right)^2+\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}\csc(x)=\sin(x)+\frac{dx}{dt}\csc(x)
$$

Let $\displaystyle{p=\frac{dx}{dt}}$

$$
p'+\cot(x)p^2-p=\sin^2(x)
$$

I do not know how to proceed from here

Comment: Thanks for the reply, this is an interesting way to approach it -- I hadn't considered it yet. I wouldn't know how to solve your or my final lines, but definitely nice to see it from a different angle.